# Eclipse 3.x unable to debug tomcat 5.5 with java 1.6.0_14?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, java-6

I'm trying to launch and debug tomcat 5.5 with a webapp in java 6.

I have set up JAVA_HOME in the tomcat's eclipse configuration (in "replace environment" mode) but I get the following error:

---

ERROR: transport error 202: gethostbyname: unknown host

ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)

JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]

FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)

---

If I launch directly the startup.bat, it works fine.

Does anybody managed to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: @ATorras. Thank you for the feedback. If you find the root cause of this issue, do not forget you can post your own answer here, and even select it as the official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a [firewall issue](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg13025.html)?

Otherwise you need to compare:

- the command line used by the eclipse launcher and
- the one generated by the startup.bat

(through a tool like [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) for instance)

Comment: Hi VonC! It's a normal localhost connection, everything is the same, only it's changed the JAVA_HOME (I checked it out and it's correct).
I'll take your second advice and compare the command line (and associated environment) with the ProcessExplorer when I could do it. Thanks!

Comment: So what was the error? I have this now too, and have no idea. I just upgraded JDK from 1.7.0 to 1.7.02 to fix an Eclipse crash bug Java was causing. And now it causes this error when I launch tomcat.

Comment: @MatthewDoucette: I think you need to leave a comment on ATorras's answer if you want a feedback from him.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue

adding

-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\bin\javaw.exe (path of javaw.exe)

in eclipse.ini file make its work

Answer (score 0):

I finally deleted the tomcat configuration and created a new one, with a proper server (tomcat 5.5 + jdk 6) and then everything worked fine.

I suppose the configuration had something wrong...

I mark VonC's answer as the correct for his useful hints.

Comment: So what was the error? I have this now too, and have no idea. I just upgraded JDK from 1.7.0 to 1.7.0_02 to fix an Eclipse crash bug Java was causing. And now it causes this error when I launch tomcat. Know if this is related?

Comment: @MatthewDoucette: Hi, do you have tried creating a new configuration from scratch and then launch it? Are you working with the same version of Tomcat? I'm afraid I didn't know more about that.

Comment: the error disappeared the next day. Perhaps Tomcat didn't compile using the new JDK or something odd. I have no idea how or when all this stuff works under the hood, which is the most annoying thing about Java development. Everything on my setup was the same except the JDK upgrade.

Comment: Wow, the error reappeared today. `FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)`. This is getting frustrating.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6626791&postcount=3

Comment: Oh, I should say that I'm using Windows 7 and Apache HTTP Server, in case it matters.